# Android retrieving a TextView results in Null. Have setContentView; Used correct id; have activity in Maifest

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, android-fragments

I'm getting a nullPointerE at run time, and have researched what problems could cause it, and I believe I suffer from none of them.

I believe the problem is that I have my layout in a fragment, and, though the app loads it correctly when I activate the intent, I think when I setContentView it doesn't find the view there.  I've tried setting the fragment as the content view, but it crashes then as well.  Also, I'm using a fragment for another screen and can access the view just fine.  I thought it might be accessing the string from the intent, but I confirmed that I'm getting a null object when I use findViewById with the if statement in the onCreate method.  The app runs just fine (without executing the inner code of course).

Here is my class:

```
public class Home extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    Intent prev = getIntent();
    String tipOfTheDay = prev.getStringExtra(Login.EXTRA_TIP);
    String welcome = prev.getStringExtra(Login.EXTRA_WELCOME);
    TextView welcomeScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewHome);
    if (welcomeScreen != null) {
        welcomeScreen.setText(welcome + "\n" + tipOfTheDay);
    }
}
```

Here is my activity_home.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.wingman.Home"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Here is my fragment_home.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.wingman.Home$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewHome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:text="@string/empty" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:contentDescription="@string/q_button" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:contentDescription="@string/calendar_button" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:contentDescription="@string/tips_button" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:contentDescription="@string/texts_button" />
```

Here is my manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.wingman"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.wingman.Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.wingman.Home"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Thanks for looking.  I'm trying to do more research on fragments, but I honestly don't know if that's even the cause.

Comment: You need to inflate your fragment_home.xml, because your textView does not exist in activity_home.xml

Comment: I'm doing some research (this is my firs time using fragments).  A little embarrassing to ask, but how do I inflate it?

Comment: Check out my answer below, you use a layout inflater. It should work if you copy and paste. If not, add getActivity() before the getSystemService(). No problem, everyone does something for the first time some day

Comment: Uhm, I have to point out that that is not an Fragment, but a Activity, I'll add a link that contains a good resource to teach you fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to set your TextView

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null)
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewHome);
```

**EDIT** You can check this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) for a tutorial on fragments

Comment: I believe this worked.  It's not crashing anymore, though the intended text is not displayed... but I'm guessing that's not related.  Thank you for the help, and the resource.

Comment: Try to hard code some text and see if it displays. I have added a link for your reference

Comment: That's what I was just trying in fact.  The TextView does display the hardcode, so I'm examining the setText method.

Comment: I meant something like this: textView.setText("This is a test");

Comment: Yep. The string "Test" I explicitly gave to textView.setText did not appear. I also coded a pre-statement in the xml file to check that the textview object was visible.  The object appears and is not executing the setText method... strange.  It's definitely grabbing from fragment_home and the proper id "textViewHome".  Is there any way the pointer for the textview variable switches object?

Comment: Try this:FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container); layout.addView(view); Add it after you have declared your view. Then I would suggest finding a decent fragment tutorial, because that does not seem right. I'll check some more if I can find the one I used

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Fragments_in_Android_-_A_Worked_Example

Comment: Couldn't find mine, but something like this should work. Or just create a new project in eclipse and set the navigation type to "Tabs" on the final screen. Good luck

Answer (score 4):

Your `TextView` is in the fragment xml, but when you are calling

```
TextView welcomeScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewHome);
```

it's looking for in the `activity_home.xml`